# Isolation between chassis and digital ground

Tags: ground, isolation

I have one doubt about the components which are used between the digital and chassis ground.
Why are diodes, high voltage capacitors, and resistors being used? What is the purpose?

[image]

Comment: What's the full circuit? What's the product?

Comment: @Andyaka This is the isolation between mounting holes(Chassis ground) and digital ground which is present in PHHHL card. Circuit updated

Comment: No, a full circuit. Without a full circuit, it's guesswork why those components are used.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want direct DC coupled connection from earthed chassis to your PCB ground. For example a desktop PC.

Sometimes you don't want a DC path if you need the PCB ground to be isolated or floating from earthed chassis. For example a laboratory power supply.

In such cases, you may still AC couple the lab power supply output with a capacitor to make a path for high frequency signals for electromagnetic compatibility. Sometimes there is a resistor to keep the chassis and PCB ground at same DC potential, to leak any accumulated charges, so that voltage difference between them will not grow too large and destroy the capacitor.

There is also sometimes an ESD diode to clamp electrostatic discharges.

In short, the components are for DC isolation and AC bypass to pass EMC tests.